# When using uiautomator, why should hint be used instead of contentDescription for EditText?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

When using uiautomator to test Android application UI behavior, it's instructed to ensure that UI is accessible. Ït is stated in documentation that "android:hint should be used instead of content description for EditText fields".
(http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#accessibility)

Why is this? Is there some disadvantage if content description is also added?

When using only android:hint with android:inputType="textPassword", the EditText remains NAF (not accessible). But when adding contentDescription, the EditText is accessible.

Also, is resource-id an attribute that could be used to reference when using uiautomator to test UI?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both content-description and hint.

Resource id is also very useful in accessing elements which has been added since Android API Level 18.

It can be used as :

```
UiObject psswrd = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.abc:id/password")); 
psswrd.click();
psswrd.setText("qwerty");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I will go with resource id. It's a shame that documentation is bit vague here.

Comment: not working for me. 
I hv latest API 19 and Android L.
It opens the keyboard but does not write into edittext.